# How do I use a Version property for NServicebus's NHibernate Saga Persister?

Tags: c#, concurrency, nservicebus, saga

Forgive me for asking a question that might have a totally obvious answer (RTFM), but how does one go about making the "Version property" mentioned [here](http://andreasohlund.net/2012/09/19/nservicebus-sagas-and-concurrency/) actually work?  The provided links to Ayende's site [here](http://ayende.com/blog/3946/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency) and the github repo [here](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/649) hint that this is possible.  There is also this other SO link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370389/nservicebus-concurrent-access-to-saga-data) that describes the same issue but does not really have a clear solution posted.  I was also unable to find NSB sample code or anything in release notes or documentation related to this feature.  However, it's critical knowledge for anyone running sagas with multiple worker threads and ReadCommited.

Is it really as simple as adding an integer property called Version to your saga data class and a timestamp/rowversion to your saga data table?  Is this really in the samples somewhere and I'm just not looking in the right place?

Also, based on the comments I've seen posted, it looks like there is a bug in NSB 3.x that involves this feature.  Will I need to upgrade to 4.x to get this feature or is there an easy way to get it working in 3.x?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Using John Simon's answer below, I ran into an bug initially using the following NSB versions:

```
NHibernate: 3.3.3.4001
NServiceBus: 4.3.1
NServiceBus.Host: 4.3.1
NServiceBus.Interfaces: 4.3.3
NServiceBus.NHibernate: 4.3.0
NServiceBus.StructureMap: 4.3.1
```

I opened [this issue on github](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.NHibernate/issues/20) and after some back & forth, tried a dev build containing a fix and got this to work.  The official fix was released in NServiceBus.NHibernate v4.4.0.

My variation on the answer was to use this with a timestamp SQL column:

```
[RowVersion]
public virtual byte[] Version { get; set; }
```

After spending a couple days hammering on it, it looks good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In v3 all you should need to do is define a version property on the saga:

```
public virtual int Version {get;set;}
```

In v4 we default to "optimistic-all" concurrency model and if you need custom row level concurrency you do the same as v3 + an attribute:

```
[RowVersion]
public virtual int Version { get; set; }
```

Comment: thanks! just to be clear, in SQL Server should this be a timestamp column or a rowversion column? According to Ayende it looks like timestamp, however I would prefer to use rowversion because the former is deprecated.  I'll give this a try today and see if I can get it up and running.

Comment: Oh, one more thing, in your second code sample did you mean "field level concurrency" for the use case when you add the attribute?  From what I was reading on github (https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/1084) row level is the default.

Comment: Updated answer to clarify the concurrency model used by default in v4

Comment: Finally was able to get back to this.  I'm having a hell of a time getting this working.  I've tried a bunch of combinations to try and avoid all the cast exceptions but no luck.  I've tried the posted example above with both a timestamp and int column in SQL both nullable and non nullable.  I've tried DateTime and byte[] in the C# saga data class with a timestamp column.  Surely this isn't supposed to be so complicated... I've updated my question to clarify

Comment: @killthrush can you raise an issue in https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.NHibernate/issues/new